# Change name of defined reference

Tags: natbib

Is there a way to change the name/label of a reference (from number to abbreviation)?
I am using `\usepackage[numbers, super, sort&compress, square]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{angew}` for my bibliography.

**Goal:** I have an article I want to cite (lets say it is ref #100) and I want the output to be AA-1 (and this expression also in the bibliography.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: The `angew` style is numeric ...

Comment: Without `natbib` and a `natbib`-compatible style like `angew` this would be possible-ish by using the optional argument of `\bibitem`. But `natbib` only supports numeric or author-year citations and uses the optional argument of `\bibitem` for something else. With your current setup you'd have to mess with internal commands to try and give certain entries special numbering. That's much trickier.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your input. i checked the manuel (https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) and found that the option `\defcitealias` in combination with `\citetalias` could do the job.